# Joomla SEF - How to hide .html from address bar?

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla3.0

I'm using Joomla 3.x. Already activated SEF links, URL rewriting and Add suffix to URL. Trying to hide the .html extension from my links. E.g.

**From:** website.com/contact.html
**To:** website.com/contact

I tried editing the .htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

But it's not working. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn OFF *Add suffix to URLs* in Joomla SEO settings.

[image: Joomla SEO Settings]

Comment: Hi, yes this worked! For some reason "Add suffix to URLs" was not working before. It was giving 404s. But now it's working fine!